# How to run an App(i called it Setup) at Application level at codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter.
i am Working on Site.
i have main application which uses Database to fetch data.
at the application level i have an (Setup) Install Directory that would Set Database settings,setting base_ul,and some other auto-loads configuration settings.
the setup will run only once.

> My Question is there any best way to run the setup app when a client run it
>   for the first time .

currently i doing it as Under:

i define a controller with the following Code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    // header("Location: details.php");
$base_url = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$base_url .= "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$base_url .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); 
$base_url = str_replace('/install', '', $base_url);
define('BASEURL', $base_url);

    header("Location: ".BASEURL.'install/', TRUE, 302);
    exit();
```

in my route.php file i reffer the above controller as default controller.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'setup';
```

working fine but not perfectly.
sorry for English grammar and if i am not clear.

Comment: Use the config file for this kind of basic data.

Comment: i am using configs files....

Answer (score 1):

i have to add setup as default controller manually,when i sale a copy or distribute which solved my problem ,
i am still working on it once i found a better answer i will edit my answer ,thanks